How to estimate conditional hazard $\lambda_c(t)$ when $T\not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp C \mid L$?
Let $C, T$ be nonnegative absolutely continuous random variables. Let $L,U$ be two arbitrary random variables. My goal is to estimate hazard function of censoring variable $C$.
Define
\begin{equation}\label{eq:hazard_censoring_observed}
\lambda_c'(t) =  \lim_{h\to 0+}h^{-1} P\{t\le C \le t+h\mid  C\ge t, T\ge t, L, U\}.
\end{equation}
Note this is the hazard function of censoring $C$ conditional on $L, U$. Under independent censoring assumption $T\!\perp\!\!\!\perp C \mid L,U$, one can assume Cox PH model and estimate the parameter using maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) approach.
I want to ask - suppose we don't observe $U$, and $T\not \!\perp\!\!\!\perp C \mid L$. That is, the independent censoring assumption is violated, how to estimate the following quantity
\begin{equation}\label{eq:hazard_censoring_observed2}
\lambda_c(t) =  \lim_{h\to 0+}h^{-1} P\{t\le C \le t+h\mid  C\ge t, T\ge t, L\}.
\end{equation}
This quantity is conditioned on the risk set, which is observable, but I can't use MLE anymore - because of the violation of independent censoring, I cannot decompose the likelihood into two separate parts as before - one that describes the event time and one that describes the censoring time, ignoring the first part and maximize only the second. Is there any other way to estimate it?
